# Sprites are rendered as black rectangles in android 4.0.x only

Tags: android, libgdx, graphics

I have some problems rendering sprites correctly on a LG optimus vu (android version 4.0) with libgdx.
Basically sprites are black rectangles, while other images that i declare as Texture are correct.
I've tested my game with android 4.2 4.3 and 5.0 and I have no problems...

Is there some difference between 4.0 and 4.2 in graphics rendering? Maybe it's Gl10 and not Gl20?

Comment: What is the difference in "sprites" vs "other images"?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED by changing the atlas dimensions from 4096x4096 to 2048x2048.
The atlas was generated using GDX Texture Packer.

Apparently, there is a problem on Android < 4.0.3 in loading big images from the assets folder.

Comment: This "problem" is quite well known, older devices even support 1024x1024 only.

Comment: @PinkieSwirl thank you for the info. Searching online for the black sprites problem didn't connect me directly to this. I hope that if someone else searches for this, founds this solution